# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k \binom{2n}{k}^2 = (-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Show that $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k \dbinom{2n}{k}^2 = (-1)^n\dbinom{2n}{n}$$ where  $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Induction didn't work, and the formula $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\dbinom{2n}{k}^2 = \dbinom{4n}{2n}$ wasn't very usefull. $(1+x)^{2n} = \displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{2n} \dbinom{2n}{r} x^{r}$ and $(1-x)^{2n} = \displaystyle\sum_{l=0}^{2n} \dbinom{2n}{l} (-1)^lx^{l}$. Multiplying the two gives me,

$$ (1+x)^{2n}(1-x)^{2n} = (1-x^2)^{2n} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \dbinom{2n}{k}(-1)^kx^{2k} = \left( \displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{2n} \dbinom{2n}{r} x^{r}\right)\left( \displaystyle\sum_{l=0}^{2n} \dbinom{2n}{l} (-1)^lx^{l}\right) $$

Coefficient of $x^{2n}$ on left side will be $\dbinom{2n}{n}(-1)^n$. But how do I exactly calculate the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the R.H.S? Please give a detailed solution

Comment: Is it true that $\left( \displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{2n} \dbinom{2n}{r} x^{r}\right)\left( \displaystyle\sum_{l=0}^{2n} \dbinom{2n}{l} (-1)^lx^{l}\right) =\displaystyle\sum_{0 \le r,l\le2n} \dbinom{2n}{r}\dbinom{2n}{l}(-1)^l x^{r+l}$ ?

Comment: The RHS is just the expanded LHS, so yes.